# Magento 1.9.X: Add customer comment to order using observer

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, event-observer, order-grid

How can I add customer comment from checkout page using observer?

Customer comment is introduced from the block with a text area. When I create new order I need to add a comment to this order using sales_order_place_before event. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the below code in your observer to add order comment:

```
$comment = "Comment to be added in the order";
$order->addStatusHistoryComment($comment)
            ->setIsVisibleOnFront(false)
            ->setIsCustomerNotified(false);
$order->save();
```

Or you can use below free extension you can use for adding order comments on the checkout page.

> https://www.ecomextension.com/order-comment.html

Answer (score 0):

Check the code below for simple add customer comment to order via observer:

```
// get the last order
$lastOrderId = $this->_getOnepage()->getCheckout()->getLastOrderId();
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($lastOrderId);

// Add the comment and save the order (last parameter will determine if comment will be sent to customer)
$order->addStatusHistoryComment('This comment is programatically added to last order in this Magento setup');
$order->save();
```